# Can Doctrine 2 show more verbose error messages?

Tags: exception, doctrine-orm

Let's say an exception is thrown because the mapping between the dcm.yml-file and the model class is not consistent. 
What I can see so far is a message:

"An error occurred in #Name-Of-Model#"
and from the stack I get the information that it must be a reflection error.

Is is possible to get more information on this error somewhere? (what exactly went wrong?)